# Java - non greedy-regex to replace partial string in longer words?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string like that:

```
  $c+350 - $c + $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]
```

Here, I only want to replace the first two **$c** (as they don't have any followed characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) with **$text**

I tried to use with Java regex pattern:

```
String a = "$c+350 - $c + $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]";
String b = a.replaceAll("\\$c[^A-Za-z0-9_]",  "\\$text")
```

but it only returns with one stripped character for each **$text**

```
b = "$text350 - $text+ $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]"
```

instead of the text it should be:

```
b = "$text+350 - $text + $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]"
```

Comment: Your expression should work as well, you just need to make `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` a look-ahead so it's not consumed and replaced:  `(?=[^A-Za-z0-9_])`. For your specific case you could also use the [word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) `\b` as Tim suggested: it will match the position between word (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and non-word characters (`[^A-Za-z0-9_]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find `\$c\b` and replace with `$text`:

```java
String input = "$c+350 - $c + $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\$c\\b", "\\$text");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
$text+350 - $text + $c_new * $c_new[x(12345)]
```